# OpenGL rotate 3D Cube on own Axis

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, cube

I have a 3D cube and I want to rotate it, but not using X,Y,Z Axis.

I would like to rotate the cube on its own Axis.

For example: I move my cube from right to left : my cube should rotate on bottom-left-axis of vertex about 90 Degree and not on Z-Axis about 90 Degree.

I tried this :

```
//prespektive...
gluPerspective(45,1.0,2.0,30.0);
//look at...
gluLookAt(0.0,2.0,  -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//try to rotate cube on bottom-right-axis
glTranslatef(-(-0.7), 0.40, -(-0.25));
glRotatef(90, 1,0,0);
glRotatef(90, 0,1,0);
glRotatef(90, 0,0,1);
glTranslatef(-0.7, 0.40, -0.25);
```

But it is not working.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you spoil projection matrix. Before rotating the cube go to `MODELVIEW` matrix mode

```
// Setup the projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(45,1.0,1.0,30.0); // front clip plane to 1.0

// Now go to modelview
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//look at...
gluLookAt(0.0,2.0,  -4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//try to rotate cube on bottom-right-axis
glTranslatef(-(-0.7), 0.40, -(-0.25));
glRotatef(90, 1,0,0);
glRotatef(90, 0,1,0);
glRotatef(90, 0,0,1);
glTranslatef(-0.7, 0.40, -0.25);
```

Comment: @Roma Kap: Did my answer help.